# Error: "There was a resource authorization issue: The pipeline is not valid."

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to build a Azure Devops pipeline and ran into this error during the run stage. Can you please help me solve this issue? Thank you

There was a resource authorization issue:

> The pipeline is not valid. Job Build_Scoring_image: Step buildscoringimage input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection aml-workspace-connection which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. Job Deploy_to_Staging: Step input kubernetesServiceConnection references service connection mlops-aks which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

I clicked 'authorize resources' next to the error and it still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suppose that your issue is could be resolved by re-configure your service connection in Project Setting.

- [Service Connection in Project Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9gSy.png)
- [Service Connection Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id7hv.png)

And your service connection would be available again in pipelines.